# how to update a collection if you already called it MongoDB Mongoos

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, collections, updating

Ok so I have a problem in which I use a collection to gather some ratings data and work with it, by the time I finish the rating update process, I have new ratings that I would like to update the collection with. However I can't call update because I get the error "Cannot overwrite model once compiled." I understand that I already called once the model to work with the data and that's why I get the error. is there any way I can update the collection? Or I will just have to workaround by creating a new collection with the latest rating, and then matching the latest ratings collection with the one I use to work with the data.

This is my code

```
let calculateRating = async () => {
  const getData = await matchesCollection().find().lean();
  const playerCollection = await playersCollection();

  const getDataPlayer = await playerCollection.find().lean();
  let gamesCounting = [];

  getDataPlayer.forEach((player) => {
    player.makePlayer = ranking.makePlayer(1500);
  });

  for (let i = 0; i < getData.length; i++) {
    const resultA = getDataPlayer.findIndex(({ userId }, index) => {
      if (userId === getData[i].userA) {
        return index;
      }
    });
    const resultB = getDataPlayer.findIndex(
      ({ userId }) => userId === getData[i].userB
    );
    const winner = getData[i].winner;

    if (getDataPlayer[resultA] === undefined) {
      continue;
    } else if (getDataPlayer[resultB] === undefined) {
      continue;
    }

    gamesCounting.push([
      getDataPlayer[resultA].makePlayer,
      getDataPlayer[resultB].makePlayer,
      winner,
    ]);
  }

  ranking.updateRatings(gamesCounting);

  let ratingsUpdate = [];

  getDataPlayer.forEach((item) => {
    let newRating = item.makePlayer.getRating();
    let newDeviation = item.makePlayer.getRd();
    let newVolatility = item.makePlayer.getVol();

    item.rating = newRating;
    item.rd = newDeviation;
    item.vol = newVolatility;

    ratingsUpdate.push(item);
  });
};
```

I try the work around with creating the new collection

Comment: Can you post the code of the `updateRatings` function?

Comment: I suspect the problem is `matchesCollection()` calls `mongoose.model` every time it is called.